# How to run a JS file containing an API POST request with node from a liquid file? - Shopify custom app development

Tags: node.js, liquid, shopify-app

I am developing a register/login custom app for a shopify store (have followed the docs, used shopify CLI)

Shopify disables CORS when POST requests are attempted from the front end code (liquid)

I have created a js file (registerCustomer.js) with said POST request which i am able to run with node to create a new customer, however i need to accept and pass form information containing name, email, phone number from a liquid file (its a block made under extensions) to registerCustomer.js

Can someone show me how to pass any information from liquid files to js files within the custom app? Any help will be greatly appreciated

The following is the liquid file where form information is captured, i've tried to send the info via an api call (not sure if this is the ideal solution)

```
<div>
  <h1 data-item="section-heading">
    Register
  </h1>
  <form
    id="contactForm"
    method="POST"
    action="/send-contact">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      placeholder="Enter your name"
      required>
    <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
    <input
      type="email"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Enter your email"
      required>
    <label for="phoneNumber">Phone number</label>
    <input
      type="tel"
      name="phoneNumber"
      placeholder="Enter your phone number"
      required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <script>
    document.getElementById('contactForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const name = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]').value;
      const email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
      const phoneNumber = document.querySelector('input[name="phoneNumber"]').value;

      const data = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber
      };

      fetch('/send-contact', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Contact information sent successfully!');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.error('Error sending contact information:', error);
      });
    });
  </script>

</div>

{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Register Inputs",
    "target": "section",
    "settings": [
      {
        "label": "form",
        "type": "html",
        "id": "register_form"
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

The follwing is registerCustomer.js

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const axios = require("axios")

const customerData = {
  customer: {
      first_name: "Steve",
      last_name: "Lastnameson",
      email: "steve.lastnameson@example.com",
      phone: "+15142546011",
      verified_email: true,
      addresses: [{
          "address1": "123 Oak St",
          "city": "Ottawa",
          "province": "ON",
          "phone": "555-1212",
          "zip": "123 ABC",
          "last_name": "Lastnameso",
          "first_name": "Mother",
          "country": "CA"
      }]
  },
};

async function registerCustomer(customerData) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`https://domain.name.com/admin/api/2022-04/customers.json`, customerData, {
        headers: {
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'password',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });
    console.log('Customer created:', response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating customer:', error);
  }

}

registerCustomer(customerData);
```

As you can see i currently have the customer information in registerCustomer.js for testing purposes, need to recieve it from the liquid file above